# Papaya ripe or over ripe

Tags: fruit

Please let me know when would we consume payaya. What is the difference between ripe and overripe papaya? I do not like soft but hard papayas which taste sweet. Please advice.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is test the fruit by pressing on the surface and see how much resistance the fruit offers. The less resistance the more ripe. Also skin and smell determines if the fruit is ready to go for a cut. I would do a couple of experiments and whola you will be the master in no time.

Comment: But then the fruit is bruised? Think of others